# How to determine how many CSS3 columns are actually being displayed (vs. the specified column-count)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of tags that are in a box that I've specified as having multiple columns:

```
#tags {
  -webkit-columns: 140px 5;
}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot - 5 columns]

The content of this list is dynamically generated.

When I resize the browser window, the number of columns collapses. e.g.:

[image]

Using jQuery / JS / CSS / etc., how can I determine how many columns are being displayed at any given time?

Comment: Could you give a fiddle or some HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specified all column width-related properties browsers will try to fit whole number of columns in content area (between left and right padding of element). So `(contentWidth + columnGap)/(columnWidth + columnGap)` rounded down will give you result.

Note that right padding may be set so high that whole column will be able to fit there - you may need to adjust computations.

You can also directly get size of column if you have an element with 100% width inside columns text.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value like this:

```
$('#tags').css('-webkit-column-count');
```

Try alerting this:

```
alert($('#tags').css('-webkit-column-count'));
```

Comment: This still only returns "5", even when just three columns are being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Alexei's answer, I figured out a solution to get the column count:

```
  var $tags = $("#tags"),
      column_width = $tags.children(':first').width(),
      container_width = $tags.width(),
      column_count = Math.floor(container_width / column_width); // in my case, sum of column gaps is less than the width of a column, so I can round down.
```